# when i login session reads only one character in php

Tags: php, session

assigning a variable to $_SESSion. when I echo that session its shows the one character example

$name="abcd";
this echo result is abcd.
$_SESSION['abcd'] = $name;
this echo result is 'a' char only

```
 <?php
include("dbConnect.php");
if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
    $name = $_POST['username'];
    $_SESSION = $name;
}
if (isset($_POST['password'])) {
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $_SESSION = $password;
}

try { 

    $conn = connect(); 

    $sql="SELECT id,employee_name,email,phone,password,image,created_on FROM handel WHERE employee_name = '$name' AND password = '$password' ";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

    close($conn);

} catch (Exception $e) { 
    //echo $e->errorMessage(); 
    close($conn);
    errorPage();
}
    // Associative array
    $data = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    print_r($data);
    echo $operatorId = $data['id'];
    echo $_SESSION['employee_name'] = $data['employee_name'];
    $_SESSION['email'] = $data['email'];
    $_SESSION['phone'] = $data['phone'];
    $_SESSION['password']=$data['password'];
    $_SESSION['image']=$data['image'];
    $_SESSION['created_on']=$data['created_on'];
 ?>
```

$name="abcd";
this echo result is abcd.
$_SESSION['abcd'] = $name;
this echo result also show 'abcd'

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually building your queries like that. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: **Never store passwords in clear text!**. Only store password hashes! Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) . If you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5 (which I _really_ hope you aren't), you can use the [password_compat library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) to get the same functionallity.

Comment: You also need a `session_start();` before you start storing stuff in the session (unless you have configured sessions to autostart).

Comment: Your question is _very_ confusing. First you say: `$_SESSION['abcd'] = $name; this echo result is 'a' char only` but then you say `$_SESSION['abcd'] = $name; this echo result also show 'abcd'`. Those are two mutually exclusive statements. Which is it?

Comment: I am used session_start()  then also same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several serious problems with your written code and the result you are expecting.

```
$_SESSION = $name;
```

This is complete novice effort. `$_SESSION` is supposed to be an array.
Always assign a session key for any value while setting session anywhere.
You are assigning it directly a string `$name`. Hence it becomes a string.
Again you are printing `$_SESSION`, So, obviously, it will return `a`, as it is a string now.
You should provide a key for your name and password like:

```
$_SESSION['any_key1'] = $data['name'];
$_SESSION['any_key2'] = $data['password'];
```

You are also vulnerable to several SQL exploitations.
Please do grasp some more PHP knowledge before implying this code practically anywhere. 
Also a good point as mentioned by @Magnus, using password as session is not a recommended approach.
You must re-think over your code.

Comment: There's no reason to store the password in a session _at all_. Also, if you were to echo `$_SESSION['abcd']` when `$_SESSION` is a string, you should get  `Warning: Illegal string offset 'abcd'`